# How to get a class name of a method by using Eclipse JDT ASTParser?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

What I am trying to do is to get a class name of a method.
For example, I want to get a class of 'until' and 'search' methods. Here are the code.

```
Query query = new Query(queryStr).until(dateStr);
QueryResult queryResult = twitter1.search(query);
```

From these examples, the expected results are **Query.until** and **SearchResource.search**.
But when I used this code below, I only got **until** and **search**, no class name. If I use MethodInvocation.getExpression(), I can get the names of the instances:new Query(queryStr) and twitter1. But they are not what I really want.

```
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() { 
            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node){
            System.out.println("Declaration of '"+node.getName()+"' at line"
                    + cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()));
            if (node.getName().toString().equals("testSearch")){
                Block block =node.getBody();

                block.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

                    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
                        //System.out.println(node.getExpression());
                        System.out.println("Name: " + node.getName());

                        return true;
                    }

                });

            }


            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You need to get the Type of twitter1, this can either be a local variable, a method parameter or a field. After you get the type you need to inspect the appropriate class/CompilationUnit. If you don't find the method there you need to inspect the superclass AND implemented interfaces. The first one is easier, you need to look at the constructor and inspect the Type the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to
[java - VariableDeclarationFragment node resolveBindind() returns null in eclipse/jdt/ast - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755640/variabledeclarationfragment-node-resolvebindind-returns-null-in-eclipse-jdt-as#12791105)
or
[java - bindings not resolving with AST processing in eclipse - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse#5803778)

Here is a simple example as RCP headless app.(with Java project "JavaProject" which contains classes Query, QueryResult, SearchResult as dummy)

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Expression;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IMethodBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation;

public class Test {

    String str = "package javaproject;" // package for all classes
            + "class Dummy {" //
            + "   void testSearch(String queryStr, String dateStr, SearchResources twitter1) {" //
            + "      Query query = new Query(queryStr).until(dateStr);" //
            + "      QueryResult queryResult = twitter1.search(query);" //
            + "   }" //
            + "}";

    public void testrun() {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
        parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);

        parser.setEnvironment( // apply classpath
                new String[] { "C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\JavaProject\\bin" }, //
                null, null, true);
        parser.setUnitName("any_name");

        final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
                if (node.getName().getIdentifier().equals("testSearch")) {
                    Block block = node.getBody();
                    block.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
                            System.out.println("Name: " + node.getName());

                            Expression expression = node.getExpression();
                            if (expression != null) {
                                System.out.println("Expr: " + expression.toString());
                                ITypeBinding typeBinding = expression.resolveTypeBinding();
                                if (typeBinding != null) {
                                    System.out.println("Type: " + typeBinding.getName());
                                }
                            }
                            IMethodBinding binding = node.resolveMethodBinding();
                            if (binding != null) {
                                ITypeBinding type = binding.getDeclaringClass();
                                if (type != null) {
                                    System.out.println("Decl: " + type.getName());
                                }
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```