# How to return the class name from a method using ASTVisitor

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

This method can get the name of the project's methods and the amount of method of lines , 
    but does not seem to get the class that declares these methods .
I already tried this post - [How to get a class name of a method by using Eclipse JDT ASTParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939857/how-to-get-a-class-name-of-a-method-by-using-eclipse-jdt-astparser), but when I use resolveMethodBinding it returns null.

```
public static void calculateAndSaveNumberMethodsFromFile(String path)throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        String codigo = Utils.getStringFromFile(path);
        codigo = RegexUtils.removeComments(codigo);

        parser.setSource(codigo.toCharArray());
        final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {

                SimpleName name = node.getName();//method name
                int qtdLinhas = 0;

                if (node.getBody() == null) {
                    LOG.info("-->Empty method!");
                    qtdLinhas = 0;
                } else {
                    qtdLinhas = (node.getBody().toString().split("\n").length - 2); //code lines method
                }

                LOG.info("Method '" + name + "' at line:" + cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()) + " Code lines: " + qtdLinhas);

                Metodo metodo = new Metodo("OK".toString(), 123);
                SingletonClass.addValue(metodo);

                return false; // do not continue to avoid usage infoxc
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bindings not resolving with AST processing in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

An important line that you are missing is:

```
 parser.setUnitName("any_name"); // set to the name of your class
```