# resolveBinding() method ALWAYS returns null

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to get the type information for variables. here is the code I'm using:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IVariableBinding;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationStatement;

public class ASTTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "package test; import java.util.ArrayList; public class Apple {    public static void main(String[] args) {        ArrayList<String> al = null;        int j =0;   }}";
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);


        TypeFinderVisitor v = new TypeFinderVisitor();
        cu.accept(v);       
    }
}

class TypeFinderVisitor extends ASTVisitor{

    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node){
        System.out.println(node.getType());
        for (Iterator iter = node.fragments().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = (VariableDeclarationFragment) iter.next();

            System.out.println(fragment.getName());

            IVariableBinding binding = fragment.resolveBinding();

            System.out.println("binding: " +binding);
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
ArrayList<String>
al
binding: null
int
j
binding: null
```

I don't understand why the binding is null, because I clearly set the binding to true.

Comment: @christoph.keimel I don't think it a duplicate of that question, the accepted answer says binding information is only available when "kind is K_COMPILATION_UNIT", which is set in the above code.

Comment: Specifically this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse/5803778#5803778

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As shown in the code, I have already set the kind to be  K_COMPILATION_UNIT.

Comment: My comment was about the first duplicate in the comments (now removed); that is why I linked to [a different question (+ answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse/5803778#5803778) which is a duplicate (and also set `K_COMPILATION_UNIT` in the question) and provides an answer (you need to call `setProject(IJavaProject)` and `setUnitName(String)`, or `setEnvironment` as well)