# How to set source path entries in order to resolve bindings in eclipse jdt ast

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to resolve bindings in one separated project. For example, the file system looks like this:

```
./
  projects/
          PPP/
             src/
                 ...
                 A.java
                 B.java
```

In A we have a method returns B type.

So I just set the unit name **/PPP/src/A.java** and set the sourcepathEntries to { "/home/user/projects/PPP" }

However, this doesn't work when I call to resolve method return types. Do u know what source path entries should I pass under this situation?

Comment: I'm sure this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse/5803778) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded. The reason is that I'm parsing a maven project.
The correct path I guess must be the root path of your packages.

e.g.

```
project/
       src/
          main/
              java/
                  edu/
                     student/
                            Code.java
```

Under this context, your Code.java will have a declared packgae **edu.student**;

So, the Unit name should be **/project/src/main/java/edu/student/Code.java**, and the source path should be **/home/..../project/src/main/java/**, remember the last "/" and the absolute path.

Therefore, the source path should be the just outer the package declaration.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the ASTParser in a standalone java project, how did you configure the unit name ( setUnitName(?)) and classPathEntries, sourcePathEntries (with the setEnviroment)